# using diffrent usernames for PyCraft

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a multiplayer snake game in PyCraft, but I've encountered a problem. Currently, I'm using this line of code:
`mc = Minecraft.create(server, port, playername)`to connect to the server. However, for a multiplayer game, I need multiple usernames to handle different collisions.

I tried using the code without specifying the username, or passing the username as an argument to other functions like `mc.player.getTilePos()`. However, I encountered an error when I didn't provide the username: `mcpi_e.connection.RequestError: b'entity.getTile()' failed`. I also searched the internet for solutions, but couldn't find any helpful answers.